# WCF C# Как отметить базовый тип из библиотеки с помощью DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf

Суть в следующем. Есть 2 службы. По структуре похожи. 
В первой службе используется тип

```
[DataContract]
public class SurveyItem : BindableBase
```

Во второй тоже есть тип, который наследуется от `BindableBase`.

Все проверил, вся структура идентична. 
Но во второй службе вылетает ошибка:

> "System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Тип
>   "AccessPanel.SurveyInvitor.Infrastructure.Models.GeneralQuotaPropertiesSurvey"
>   не может быть производным от типа, который не отмечен с помощью
>   атрибута DataContractAttribute или SerializableAttribute. Отметьте
>   базовый тип "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase" с помощью
>   атрибута DataContractAttribute или SerializableAttribute либо удалите
>   их из производного типа."

Почему в одном случае ругается, а в другом нет?
Возможно ли как-то отметить этим атрибутом базовый класс?

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать использовать альтернативный сериализатор, поставив атрибут `[XmlType]` вместо `[DataContract]`.

Но, вообще говоря, вы делаете что-то странное. Сообщения, передаваемые через WCF - это DTO (Data Transfer Objects), они не могут быть моделями вида.

От модели вида (VM, View Model) ожидается неизменяемость ссылки на объект - и изменяемость свойств. В вашем же случае при каждом вызове метода будет создаваться новый объект.